# Remedy subtle difference between generated and expected SOAP message

Tags: java, wcf, soap, interop, message

I'm trying to establish some communictaion between services hosted on different platforms: .net <-> java. It's not possible for me to change anything in the Java part. This is third party software to which we have no access.

My troubles basically boil down to a subtle difference in what the services is expecting (tested with SoapUI) and what WCF is sending (tested via tracing).

Expected (or at least allowed):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:ser="http://servicenamespace/">      
    <s:Header /> 
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">      
        <ser:method >           
            <param1/>
            <param2>xxx</param2>
            <param3>zzz</param3>        
        </ser:method>   
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

What .NET actually tries to send:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header/>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <method xmlns="http://servicenamespace/">
            <param1/>
            <param2>xxx</param2>
            <param3>zzz</param3>
        </method>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you see, the difference is subtle. What the servicen is expecting is the namespace declaration in the header tag... 
Is there some way to fix this, preferably in a low impact (e.g. not intercepting and changing the message) manner? Perhaps by using attributes in some other manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the difference is less subtle than you think and it is not about the placement of the namespace declarations. It is about the namespace of the `paramX` elements.

- In your first example, the `paramX` elements are in the *null*-namespace;
- in your second example, the `paramX` elements are in `http://servicenamespace/`.

This kind of difference must be evident in the XML Schema of your message body and the tool you use to build the code from the Schema must respect that. So perhaps you can make an intervention into either the code-building tool or the generated code.

Comment: Indeed an intervention was needed. I resorted to manually creating the SOAP message and POSTing it to the service. A good lesson to not just trust 'the framework' :)